# Facebook Graph API Wall Feed not returning all images

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I'm trying to make a request against a specific wall feed to pull ALL the (public) images posted by ANY user to the wall. My request seems to return any posts made by any user but only the photos that were uploaded by the user passing in the auth token. Is it possible to get a request for all public photos on the wall?